# What is the cause of the new Float32Array time consuming exception?

Tags: javascript, arrays, webpack

```
let arr = []

for(let i = 0; i < 11308608; i++){

arr.push(Math.random() * 1000)

}

console.time('load')

a = new Float32Array(arr)

console.timeEnd('load')
```

Open a new blank page, open the console, and execute this code, typically in tens of milliseconds, no more than 100ms.

However, it is commonly used in projects over 1500ms.

The reason why I found this is that the project needs to load more 3D resources. When optimizing the performance, I found that the optimized effect in the static page demo was very good, while the effect was very poor when used in the project.

Basically, it takes 10s in the demo, but more than 30s in the project.

After a lot of hard work, we found this code in `three.module.js:40591`:

`const typedArray = new TYPED_ARRAYS[ attribute.type ]( attribute.array );`

This is a time consuming exception when writing to an array.

After trying to remove the VUE, removing all dependencies and leaving only a blank page, the console execution of the above test code still does not take effect.

In a build project, remove all JS files to avoid time-consuming exceptions.

Executing this code on the React project will also result in a time-consuming exception.

According to the preliminary judgment, it is webpack, but it cannot be solved yet.

Comment: Have you configured webpack to do transpilation and load polyfills for typed arrays?

Comment: I found an override of the type array in core-js, is that it? How to deal with it?

Comment: Yes, core-js is a polyfill, and if it overrides the typed array constructor it's likely a much slower implementation than the native. So a) why are you loading core-js at all? It might depend on the browser-compat settings of babel. b) why does core-js override the native functions if they are available? This might be a bug or a configuration issue.